# Positioning the Image within an Image (View)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I’m working with an image, and I would like to adjust the position of the image within the view.  Currently, I’m setting the Aspect to AspectFill, and it’s chopping off the top of the image, so I would like to bring it down a few pixels.

Has anyone dealt with this, or is that possible with Xamarin.Forms at this moment?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `AspectFill` fill the bounds, eventually clipping at the edges. The ratio will be respected;
- `AspectFit` won't clip, and the ratio will be respected too. so you might have letter boxing;
- `Fill` will fill the bounds, stretching the image.

`AspectFit` is probably what you want, and if you don't set the `Image.BackgroundColor`, you won't see the difference.

Comment: I was trying to avoid letter boxing, but I'll accept this because of the BackgroundColor tip. I ended up getting it to work by adding padding to the top of the image. It wasn't the solution I was hoping for, but it worked. Thanks